# send the PUSH notification to multiple users Through FCM

Tags: php, android, curl, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send the PUSH notification to the Multiple USERS through PHP script. When I run my script it shows the result successful, but on my device I am not getting any Notification.

But when I use the FCM console, I got the Notifications on my Device.

PHP script:

```
<?php
        function send_notification ($tokens, $message)
        {
                $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
                $fields = array(
                         'registration_ids' => $tokens,
                         'data' => $message,
                         'click_action' => ACTIVITY_CIRCULAR
                        );
                $headers = array(
                        'Authorization:key = my key',
                        'Content-Type: application/json'
                        );
           $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
       $result = curl_exec($ch);
       if ($result === FALSE) {
           die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
       }
       curl_close($ch);
       return $result;
        }


        $conn = mysqli_connect("connection set-up");
        $sql = "Select FirebaseID From Coordinates";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        $tokens = array();
//var_dump(result);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        $tokens[] = $row["FirebaseID"];
                }
        }
    var_dump($tokens);

        mysqli_close($conn);
        $message = array("message" => "Hello World");
        $message_status = send_notification($tokens, $message);
        echo $message_status;
 ?>
```

My result:

```
{"multicast_id":6386552330832519***,"success":2,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1477******764957%e8a8d907f9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1477293027764959%e8a8d907f9f***cd"}]}
```

**EDIT :** Is there any way to check where the message is failing because it shows the Successful in Result...but it doesn't reach to device

Answer (score 1):

If you user is more than 1k then you have to chunk you array because FCM registaion_ids not allowed more than 1k id at a time :

```
$value = array_chunk($userList,900);


            foreach ($value as $val)
            {
                $db->sendPushCustomNew("test" . " Posted a Gallery", $createdDate, $val, "1", "Gotcha!", 0, 0, 0);
            }
```

Then You have to configure you're notification send function like bellow :

```
function sendPushCustomNew($message, $currentDate, $tokens, $notificationType, $title, $latitude, $longitude, $memberID)
{
    //error_log("IN_PUSH");
    $curl = curl_init();
    $fields = array(
        'data' => array(
            'notificationType' => $notificationType,
            'title' => $title,
            "message" => "" . $message,
            "time" => "" . $currentDate,
            'latitude' => $latitude,
            'longitude' => $longitude
        ),
        'registration_ids' => $tokens
    );
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($fields),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "authorization: ******",
            "cache-control: no-cache",
            "content-type: application/json",
            "postman-token: ***"
        )
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
   
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please check that you have saved the device id properly or not ,and also check that you have used the same server key as per project android key ,check your google account

Comment: Both are correct and i also update my device id regularly in my db

Answer (score 0):

use this php code its works in your case

```
    <?php
    // API access key from Google API's Console
    define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'YOUR-API-ACCESS-KEY-GOES-HERE' );
    $registrationIds = array( $_GET['id'] );
    // prep the bundle
    $msg = array
    (
        'message'   => 'here is a message. message',
        'title'     => 'This is a title. title',
        'subtitle'  => 'This is a subtitle. subtitle',
        'tickerText'    => 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here',
        'vibrate'   => 1,
        'sound'     => 1,
        'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
        'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
    );
    $fields = array
    (
        'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
        'data'          => $msg
    );

    $headers = array
    (
        'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL,
 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
    $result = curl_exec($ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
    echo $result;
```

Comment: then fetch registration id from your db then use in code

Comment: i did it and also check whether is working or not using var_dump

Comment: When i hardcode the Registration ID Array, also same problem is arise

Comment: @NiteshPareek is registration ids equals to device tokens?

Answer (score 0):

inside your project you are adding registration id that you get when you create a google api console account from there you ll get server key and android key https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library?project=tabzen-1341,see the screenshot and read the google guidl[image]

Comment: everything is fine in my code and Result is also shows Successful but the problem is i m not getting any message....Help me

Comment: @techDigi - did you ever resolve this issue?  I'm having the same problem, I get success in the response but never receive the notification.  Do I have to add the server I'm running this from to a list of white listed servers to ALLOW it to send?